# Can 3D ocean farms provide food and biofuel far more sustainably than other sources?

Tags: nutrition, economics, agriculture, ecology, sustainability

This [article in The Nation](http://www.thenation.com/article/this-former-fisherman-is-now-farming-the-most-sustainable-food-on-earth-underwater/) contains *an excerpt from “Ecological Redemption: Ocean Farming in the Era of Climate Change,” a lecture by Bren Smith given at the Thirty-Fifth Annual E. F. Schumacher Lectures on October 24, 2015.*.  The lecture reads like one big advertisement for growing ocean vegetables in *zero-input farms*.  Reading it makes one wonder why this technology doesn't feed the world already.  For example, it claims:

> This is zero-input food that requires no fresh water, no fertilizer, no feed, no arid land—making it hands down the most sustainable food on the planet. And as the price of fertilizer, water, and feed goes up, zero-input food is going to be the most affordable food on the planet. The economics of it will drive us to eat ocean greens.

and

> Seaweeds are a powerful source of zero-input biofuel; we can produce 2,000 gallons of ethanol per acre—that’s a 30 times higher yield than soybeans and five times more than corn. According to the Department of Energy, if you were to take a network of our farms equaling half the size of the state of Maine, you could replace all the oil in the United States.

Is it accurate to state that the three-dimensional ocean farms described in the lecture provide zero-input food, zero-input biofuels, and are therefore the most sustainable food or biofuels on the planet?

I recognise there may be no established definition of *zero-input farming*.  Therefore, I am satisfied if any research shows that this form of farming is far more sustainable than existing farming, taking into account negative externalities including pollution and resource depletion.

I'm sceptical because I believe that if it were as amazing as the lecture states, big business would be making billions off it already.  There must be a catch.

[image: The Economic Argument, XKCD]

<sup>The Economic Argument.  By Randall Munroe, XKCD.</sup>

See also:

- [Greenwave, 3D Ocean Farming](http://greenwave.org/3d-ocean-farming/) for additional claims.
- [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/sustainable-business/2015/oct/22/greenwave-ocean-farming-bren-smith-fuller-challenge-sustainability-climate-change), 22 October 2015

Comment: I don't mean to be obtuse, but is there a reasonable definition for "zero-input" farming? My quick Google searches failed, especially to distinguish it from fishing or hunting.

Comment: @Oddthinking I don't know.  I *suppose* it means a form of farming where the farmer does not need to add nutrients, but I don't know.

Comment: Tricky. I would have thought, by that definition, it would include fishing, in which case big business are making [billions](https://www.msc.org/healthy-oceans/the-oceans-today/the-seafood-economy) off it already.

Comment: @Oddthinking I don't think fishing counts as farming. I would understand farming to mean dedicated food-growing in a limited plot of land. I will edit the question to try to make it more answerable. What's described in the article is clearly different from and in fact explicitly contrasted to (non-sustainable) fishing.

Comment: Looks like [they won the 2015 Fuller challenge](https://bfi.org/dymaxion-forum/2015/10/greenwave-wins-2015-fuller-challenge), so it looks like it's real.

Comment: @Oddthinking - What gerrit said (about fishing not being farming) - PLUS, most fishing is not considered sustainable when scaled up (you have a limited capacity to produce more fish even discarding complex ecological stability issues) - at its basic root, because fish aren't the bottom of ecologic system.

Comment: @user5341: I am not saying that fishing (as practiced) is sustainable. Nor am I saying that zero-input farming is sustainable (because that would be an answer to the question). I am saying the term "zero-input farming" is - to me - a marketing term that I've never heard before and can't find a reasonable definition. Without a definition there is little hope of answering this question, so I am appealing for one.

Comment: Possibly to soon to tell. While skimming the site, I found no technical or scientific literature. Has anyone had more luck?

Comment: @mart They also claim the technology is open-source and free for anyone to use, so it should not be an issue of company secrets...

Comment: @Oddthinking - I suspect there's a less buzz-marketing more precise term for what was being described. I agree fully that merely "zero-input farming" is far less precise than needed.